# I can't run code or debug of my python file in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The error says this:

```
There was an error in starting the debug server. Error = {"code":"ECONNREFUSED","errno":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3000}
```

And the setting of my 'Python Attach' in launch.json looks like this:

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Attach",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "port": 3000,
        "secret": "my_secret",
        "host": "localhost"
    },
```

Looks like something's missing. I realized that there's no debugOption but I don't know how to fix it. It used to work fine before the update. Any help?

Comment: You are attaching a debugger onto port 3000. Is your application running on that port?

Comment: Also attaching a debugger to a running application is bugging at the moment. You may want to consider launching your application with a debugger instead or using ipdb or any other debugger

Comment: @OluwafemiSule No I don't know how it when and how the port went there. I never debug through internet. Do you know what's the right setting to debug in the 'DEBUG CONSOLE'?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below simple setting by  replace or select during debug.

```
{
"name": "Python",
"type": "python",
"request": "launch",
"stopOnEntry": true,
"program": "${file}",
"pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
"debugOptions": [
    "RedirectOutput"
]
}
```

Further, For for me wrong /etc/hosts configuration caused the issue 'error:listen eaddrnotavail ' Adding for somebody who faces the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem, which I think may have been caused by having imported too many configurations that somehow conflicted with one another. When I got the error I clicked on the option to "View json" file. From there, I basically cleared out the file and removed all of the lines that referred to python. So it was like a blank settings file. I closed it, saved it and then ran my code again. This time, VSCode prompted me to select the environment. I selected "Python" which was listed just like that and the code ran just fine.